# dplyr solution to split dataset, but keep IDs in same splits

Tags: r, split, dplyr, tidyr

I'm looking for a dplyr or tidyr solution to split a dataset into n chunks. However, I do not want to have any single ID go into multiple chunks. That is, each ID should appear in only one chunk.

For example, imagine "test" below is an ID variable, and the dataset has many other columns.

```
test<-data.frame(id= c(1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,6,7,8,9,9,9,9,10),
             val = 1:16)
out <- test %>% select(id) %>% ntile(n = 3)
out
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
```

The ID=4 would end up in chunks 1 and 2. I am wondering how to code this so that all ID=4 end up in the same chunk (doesn't matter which one). I looked at the split function but could not find a way to do this.

The desired output would be something like

```
test[which(out==1),]
```

returning

```
  id val
1  1   1
2  2   2
3  3   3
4  4   4
5  4   5
6  4   6
7  4   7
8  4   8
```

Then if I wanted to look at the second chunk, I would call something like test[which(out==2),], and so on up to out==n. I only want to deal with one chunk at a time. I don't need to create all n chunks simultaneously.

Comment: What is the desired output? In `dplyr` it would be best to put this variable as a column in a data frame and use `group_by` to do whatever computation on each `ID` group. You seem to want to create multiple objects per group, which is not recommended.

Comment: Updated. I think it's much clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a data frame, then use `group_by` and `mutate` to add columns:

```
test<-data_frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,6,7,8,9,9,9,9,10),
                 value = 1:16)
out <- test %>%
  mutate(new_column = ntile(id,3))
out

# A tibble: 16 x 3
      id value new_column
   <dbl> <int>      <int>
 1     1     1          1
 2     2     2          1
 3     3     3          1
 4     4     4          1
 5     4     5          1
 6     4     6          1
 7     4     7          2
 8     4     8          2
 9     6     9          2
10     7    10          2
11     8    11          2
12     9    12          3
13     9    13          3
14     9    14          3
15     9    15          3
16    10    16          3
```

Or given Frank's comment you could run the `ntile` function on distinct/unique values of the id - then join the original table back on id:

```
test<-data_frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,6,7,8,9,9,9,9,10),
                 value = 1:16)
out <- test %>%
  distinct(id) %>%
  mutate(new_column = ntile(id,3)) %>%
  right_join(test, by = "id")
out
# A tibble: 16 x 3
      id new_column value
   <dbl>      <int> <int>
 1     1          1     1
 2     2          1     2
 3     3          1     3
 4     4          2     4
 5     4          2     5
 6     4          2     6
 7     4          2     7
 8     4          2     8
 9     6          2     9
10     7          2    10
11     8          3    11
12     9          3    12
13     9          3    13
14     9          3    14
15     9          3    15
16    10          3    16
```

Comment: I updated my question a bit. Hopefully that explains it better.

Comment: @Frank Still not what I'm looking for because ID==4 ends up in the output from new_column == 1, 2, and 3. I want all ID==4 to be in the same subset, and likewise for the other values of ID.

Comment: @drj3122, now I'm confused. What role does the `ntile` function play in all of this?

Comment: I thought originally that ntile might be the function I need, but I think I was wrong

Comment: @Frank's solution was exactly what I was trying to do